# Comparing PDFs generated using two different versions of IText (version 2 and 7)

Tags: html, pdf, itext

Currently, we are using (IText version 2 + Flying saucer) for creating PDFs from HTML and we are planning to migrate to IText version 7 (I am using trial version now) because of limitations with version 2. As part of the initial analysis, I have generated the PDFs using both version 2 and version 7 for the same HTML.

I tried to compare the pdf bytes. Some of the PDFs matched but some of them do not.

I want to know if we can rely on pdf byte comparison for comparing the PDFs generated using two different of IText for the same HTML. Is there any better way of comparing these two PDFs?

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know if we can rely on pdf byte comparison for comparing the PDFs generated using two different of IText for the same HTML.

No. First of all you can't rely on direct byte comparison because iText inserts a creation date and a document ID which will change even with the same iText version.

> Is there any better way of comparing these two PDFs?

We use the [CompareTool class](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.1.2/index.html?com/itextpdf/kernel/utils/CompareTool.html) to get around this internally for testing. The `compareVisually()` which uses [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) *might* be sufficient for you if you expect the visual output to be the same down to the pixel even if the underlying content changed (e.g drawing 4 lines vs directly drawing a square).

That being said I doubt the visual output will be the same. pdfHTML and iText 7 have gone through vast improvements over the years so it is very likely there are some visual bugs/discrepancies in 2 that are no longer present in 7, or HTML tags/CSS properties that are supported in pdfHTML that are not supported in FlyingSaucer.

Disclaimer: I work for iText.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over an open source project a while ago and a quick search turned up another one. I didn't try them out for myself but I would give it a try:

https://github.com/vinsguru/pdf-util

https://github.com/red6/pdfcompare

Both are based on PdfBox and offer an pixel-by-pixdel imge comparison but also other features like text comparison etc.